# INotifyPropertyChanged PropertyChangedEventHandler event is always null

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to get my hands on WPF, and I have encountered a small problem when updating, mainly that I am getting the old data displayed while the new data is correctly updated in the XML file.  I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged as follows :-

```
public class Products : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _prodId;
    public string ProdID
    {
        get { return _prodId; }
        set
        {
            _prodId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProdID");
        }
    }

    private string _prodName;
    public string ProdName
    {
        get { return _prodName; }
        set
        {
            _prodName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProdName");
        }
    }

    private string _prodPrice;
    public string ProdPrice
    {
        get { return _prodPrice; }
        set
        {
            _prodPrice = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProdPrice");
        }
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

and then the update is as follows :-

```
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            if (nodeList[i].ChildNodes[0].InnerText == strID)
            {
                Products products = new Products();
                products.ProdName = strName;
                products.ProdPrice = strPrice;
                nodeList[i].ChildNodes[1].InnerText = strName;
                nodeList[i].ChildNodes[2].InnerText = strPrice;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

The XML is being saved correctly with the new ProdName and Price, however when I display the listView after the update, i am still getting the wrong values.

I am binding the Products like this:-

```
    public static List<Products> LoadProduct()
    {
        string fileName = "Products.xml";
        List<Products> ListProdRecords = new List<Products>();
        // Execute the query using the LINQ to XML
        var prods = from p in XElement.Load(fileName).Elements("Product") select p;
        foreach (var product in prods)
        {
            Products lProduct = new Products
            {
                ProdID = product.Element("ProductId").Value,
                ProdName = product.Element("ProductName").Value,
                ProdPrice = product.Element("Price").Value
            };

            ListProdRecords.Add(lProduct);
        }
        return ListProdRecords.ToList();
    }
```

here is the binding code :-

```
    private void LoadProducts()
    {
        List<Products> productList = new List<Products>();
        productList = ProductDAL.LoadProduct();
        listView1.DataContext = productList;
    }
```

public static void UpdateProduct(string strID, string strName, string strPrice)
        {
            string fileName = "Products.xml";

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(fileName);

        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Products/Product");
        int i = 0;
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            if (nodeList[i].ChildNodes[0].InnerText == strID)
            {
                Products products = new Products();
                products.ProdName = strName;
                products.ProdPrice = strPrice;
                nodeList[i].ChildNodes[1].InnerText = strName;
                nodeList[i].ChildNodes[2].InnerText = strPrice;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Any help on what's wrong?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Can you post code where you are binding listview to your collection? Make sure your collection is ObservableCollection is also calling OnPropertyChanged

Comment: It may be less confusing when your class representing a single Product is called Product. Also the Prod Prefix is redundant

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see, what the *newly created products* in your loop have to do with a `listView`. You don't add them to a list or add them to the `listView` in another way.
Or in other words: The creation of those instances inside your loop is completely useless and will be removed by the optimizer.
You need to update the instances of the `Products` class that are in the list you bound to the `listView`.

Comment: I am loading the products like this

Comment: public static List<Products> LoadProduct()
        {
            string fileName = "Products.xml";
            List<Products> ListProdRecords = new List<Products>();
            // Execute the query using the LINQ to XML
            var prods = from p in XElement.Load(fileName).Elements("Product") select p;

Comment: foreach (var product in prods)
            {
                Products lProduct = new Products
                {
                    ProdID = product.Element("ProductId").Value,
                    ProdName = product.Element("ProductName").Value,
                    ProdPrice = product.Element("Price").Value
                };

                ListProdRecords.Add(lProduct);
            }
            return ListProdRecords.ToList();
        }

Comment: @Johann: Please update your question with this info. It is unreadable as a comment.

Comment: @Johann: Besides, that doesn't show, how you bind that list to the listView and even if you bind that list correctly to the listView, it wouldn't change anything in my answer, because the items you create in your loop have nothing to do with the items in the list!

Comment: Hi Daniel, that is what I wish to know how to do, binding the list correctly to the ListView.  I am quite new to WPF

Comment: @Johann: Why don't you just ask that than? You were asking something else completely. Besides, you don't show your binding code, so how should we correct it?

Comment: Hi daniel, added the binding code.  I did not ask that because coming from a c# background, I could not understand exactly what was going wrong.

Comment: @Johann: You normally bind the list to the `ItemSource` property. But that's not the problem. What is the problem? **See my answer**

Comment: Hi Daniel, re your answer "You need to update the instances of the Products class that are in the list you bound to the listView." What do you mean exactly by update the instances?  If I am loading the XML file, and its already updated with the new values, than shouldn't it display correctly in the list when I bind it to it?

Comment: @Johan: Maybe the order of your actions is different than I thought. Please tell me what you do first, second etc. I thought you were doing this: (1) Load Products from XML. (2) Bind list to listView. (3) Update Xml.

Comment: Hi Daniel, when clicking on the Update Button, I am calling the ProductDAL.UpdateProduct(strID, strName, strPrice); which in turn will call the UpdateProduct as displayed in the edited code.  After the update, I am just closing this window and loading the ProductList.xaml

Comment: The ProductList.xaml will load the products from the XML file, which is now updated, however, the ListView is still showing the same products. If I close the window and load it again, it will show the correct updated Products

Comment: @Johann: Hm. Do you encounter the same problem, when you bind the list to `ItemSource` instead of `DataContext`?

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes it does.  I beleive it has to do something with ObservableCollection as Lav said.  I will investigate a bit how to implement this.

Comment: @Johann: That's not the problem. I just tried to reproduce your problem and couldn't. My code is very simple: In the constructor of the window, I bind a list with two items. And after the button click, I bind a new list with two new items. The list updates without problem. There must be something else in your code. Are you sure, you re-read the XML file after you have updated it?

Comment: HI Daniel, yeah I will go through my code again, since before was adding the product and refreshing the list correctly, while now, after I implemented the update, its not.  Will keep you updated.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Daniel, managed to find the problem.  basically I had the filename as string fileName = "Products.xml"; and I had to change it to string fileName = "C:\\Testing\\WpfProducts\\WpfProducts\\Products.xml";

Comment: Yeah its the last thing I could think of :)  At least I found it.  Thanks for all your help mate